# Is this smelly error handling?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

This seems like a pretty efficient way to do error handling, but I want to know how to do it correctly if this is smelly:

```
Class Widget
    ...
    Public Function IsValid() As Boolean
        If (some condition isnt met) Then
            Throw New ApplicationException("Error message")
        ElseIf (some other condition isnt met) Then
            Throw New ApplicationException("Another error message")
        End If
        Return True
    End Function
    ...
End Class

... (somewhere else)...
Public Function DoAwesomeStuff(id As Integer) As String
    Dim w As Widget() = Widget.GetWidget(id)
    If w.IsValid Then
        Do Awesome Things
    End If
    Return a string of some sort
End Sub

... (somewhere elser)...
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Function Add(ByVal id As Integer) As String
    Try
       //.ToJson is an Extension Method that serializes an obj to JSON
       Return New With {.Message = DoAwesomeStuff(id)}.ToJson
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return New With {.Message = "Error: " & ex.Message, .Error = True}.ToJson
    End Try
End Function
```

And then in the javascript I check for an `Error` property in the response and handle accordingly. It seems like it works ok for me, but I am not sure if this is smelly. I know you're not supposed to use `Try/Catch` blocks for control flow, I'm just not sure if this qualifies as control flow or not.

Comment: My logic is that if I throw an exception I can pass along the error message to be displayed to the user, whereas returning false still leaves me without any idea why the validation failed. Assuming I have several validation rules, this could be confusing and/or cause double-validation.

Comment: @StackOverflowException - How else are you going to return a meaningful error message up the stack and to the web service clients?

Comment: For me, the fact that you've created a branch that cannot be executed seemed a bit odd. IsValid can never return false so why return a value at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has a **[vexing exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)** smell.

Users of the `IsValid` function would expect it to return `True` or `False`.

Exceptions should be used in unexpected cases, for example, if some variable needed to evaluate the validity in your `IsValid` function is not properly initialized.

If you want to have a validation failure message along with the validation status, consider using a `ByRef` parameter for example, something like:

```
Public Function IsValid(ByRef invalidReason as String) As Boolean
    If (some condition isnt met) Then
        invalidReason = "Error message"
        return False
    ElseIf (some other condition isnt met) Then
        invalidReason = "Another error message"
        return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: thanks maxim. this is exactly what i'm going to do.

Answer (score 1):

Looks perfectly valid to me.

Since this is on a system boundary (web service), it is perfectly OK to try and return an error if there was an exception.

The only smell here is in the `IsValid` method - it really shouldn't be the one throwing exceptions. The calling method should (when a false is returned), or even the lower level methods that you call in the `If` clauses (assuming you have encapsulated them in their own methods).

Comment: how do i get the error message back from `IsValid` telling me what went wrong if `IsValid` returns a boolean value?

Comment: @Jason - you get the exception message. Just ensure that is either thrown by the caller when it gets a _false_, or that the validation itself throws it.